# Detect angle of edges in GeometryNodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have been trying for some time with geometry nodes to detect the angle between two edges that are connected by a vertex.

My intention is to use that to spawn cubes or spheres at each vertex depending on whether or not the connecting two edges are convex or concave like the example in my image.

[image: example vertex group]

Comment: I've asked this specific question in several forums, and the only answer that seems to work at all involves extruding all the edges and then using a node to get the angles between the faces you've extruded.  I hope someone here has a better one.

Comment: @MartyFouts oh interesting, I haven't come across that info. If you can could you point me to some of them forum posts ?

Comment: Looks like someone has just posted an example.  If that's not enough let me know and I'll dig things up.

Comment: If your question was solved, please be so kind and mark the answer that contributed to the solution as "Accepted Answer". This will make it easier for others to see which way leads to the solution, and the question will no longer appear as unsolved. Thank you! Here you can find more information: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you still didn't get a solution to your question, please be kind enough to address it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It depends a bit on how you generate the edges, with a clean mesh like that you could transfer the angle of some adjacent edge to each vertex and use 'Signed Angle' to pick an instance object... if you have only the edges it's more difficult, besides it's somehow arbitrary what's a 90 or a 270 angle

[image: node setup]

[first blend](https://www.dropbox.com/s/px30or0e0w1bv12/EEE.blend?dl=1) file

---

Here's another option with pure edges, it checks against a vertical vector, normal to the edges plane. I tried converting edges to curves to be able to use L/R handles for each point, it also orders indexes  as a bonus...

[image: node setup]

[second blend](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h272rfcirfy7lun/THE.blend?dl=1) file

and if you need the angles as the title suggests something like this could help...
maybe combine both setups to get signed angles

[image: node setup]