# Geometry Nodes: Whether the curve rotates clockwise or counter-clockwise?

Tags: geometry-nodes, normals

I'm trying to place two instance objects on curve turns using geometry nodes.

I need to define

1. Points where the curve turns
2. Type of rotation -- clockwise or counterclockwise

I used Normal node to detect points of rotations.
[image]

But it works wrong.
[image]

Is it possible to use the Normal or Curve Tangent nodes for this issue? Perhaps there is another approach.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender.SE! This might be helpful (...maybe a duplicate?): https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/259550/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this issue by using the [example](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/259575/145249) I mentioned in the comment (strictly speaking, it is a duplicate from my point of view, but I am writing the answer anyway so that this particular question is fully answered):

[image]

1. Capture the direction of the corner per point. The trick with the `Curve Handle Positions` helps you. If you create the cross product from these positions, and then compare it with the up vector, you will always get $0$ or $1$, depending on the direction of the curve.
2. Then convert the curve to points, because this will give you the rotation of each point, which you can use as a basis for `Align Euler to Vector`.
3. Finally, instantiate at the intermediate points (I assume in this example that you do not want to create objects at the first and last point) one of the two objects from your collection.

Make sure that the rotation of the objects is ok, or correct it according to your ideas.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. Will Curve Handle Positions work after Resample node? I'd like to fill in the straight sections with square blocks.

Comment: I assume that Cross Product on straight sections should give a zero vector. Thus, it would be possible to select points on straight sections by comparing with the zero vector. But so far it doesn't work.

Comment: @PavelTrufanov To create instances on the lines between the vertices, I would choose this solution: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPuk1.jpg

Comment: Exactly what is needed. Thank you!