# How can curves created from a cubic mesh have a consistent tangent direction in relation to the other 3 curves that share the original quad?

Tags: geometry-nodes

#### Problem Description

After splitting edges and scaling elements, when the 4 edges of a face are converted to *individual* curves, it seems that almost always one curve will have a tangent in the opposite direction.

For example, looking at the factor value from 0 to 1 from point "4" on the top face, it can be seen that:

4-5: clockwise 
5-6: clockwise
6-7: clockwise
7-4: *counter-clockwise*

[image]

It can also be seen that when the tangent value is viewed, one curve is black while the others are white or vise versa.

[image]

#### Application Goal

Ideally, in this proof of concept, each instance would have:

1. An axis pointing in the same direction as the curve (all uniform either clockwise or counter-clockwise)
2. An axis pointed towards the opposite edge
3. An axis pointing in the same direction as the original face's z-normal:

[image]

If this is accomplished, then, should the instances have an additional line rotated 135° from the line pointing towards the opposite edge, they should be parallel and point in the same direction:

[image]

[image]

I have referenced many questions, but these two seemed to be the most relevant (the first of which provided a node group that is in the blend file below thanks to quellenform):

[How to correct curve tilt, tangents and normals of a curve?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/271761/how-to-correct-curve-tilt-tangents-and-normals-of-a-curve?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Geometry Nodes: Whether the curve rotates clockwise or counter-clockwise?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/286234/geometry-nodes-whether-the-curve-rotates-clockwise-or-counter-clockwise/286321#286321)

Any help would be very much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This group takes a different approach to yours. The strategy:

- Create a Curve Line for every face-corner on the mesh
- Set endpoint  0 of each spline on the sampled position of each corner of the mesh
- Set endpoint  1 of each spline on the sampled position of each corner, offset by 1, in its face
- Tilt each spline through the signed angle between its own Normal, and the underlying face normal

[image]

The result is 1 spline for each edge of the mesh, with its Tangent (Z) down the edge (anticlockwise to face-normal), and its Normal (X) set to the normal of the underlying face-corner. ( Y is constrained )

Here, shown with arrows instanced on the curves, aligned to the curves'
'Ŕotations'

[image]

In the case of rectilinear quads, -Y is the direction towards the opposite edge.

[image]

Comment: Wow. This setup even covers n-gons. What a brilliant idea to eschew trying to manipulate the original edges and just arrange new curves. As someone who is trying to learn more math for GN I really appreciate your explanations. Thank you very much.

Comment: @bobhasajetpack    Cheers! Forgive me for not going a bit further, with your 135° thing, but I didn't fully understand that, and figured step 1 might be enough.

Comment: It absolutely was enough. The occurance of parallel 135° line alignment (assuming 90° corners) was just my hypothesis should the xyz of the curves have "correct" orientation. Sure enough, your answer was perfect https://imgur.com/a/MyuhoMB