# How to model machicolations using geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

So years ago, early in my CG learning journey I had trouble trying to understand how to model machicolations.  As in these things:[image]

and eventually learned how to get really good at modeling in general. Now I need help making them again. But this time in geometry nodes.

So the only thing I'm having a lot of trouble on, is finding out out to select the corner instances, so that I can replace those instances with another object.

[image]

Is there a way to select instances based on their rotation?  I tried using the instance rotation but it didn't work.  Either I was using it wrong or my whole mindset was wrong.  Anyway, any help is appreciated because after 4 courses on geometry nodes, I still can't seem to understand which nodes to use at what points.  Here's the file if that helps:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FzzQl3WCXCvHCbu9dCsK5S38HXdgRJ0Y/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/259550/detect-angle-of-edges-in-geometrynodes