# With geometrynodes how do i rotate mesh so it follows the detected face angle

Tags: geometry-nodes, procedural

How do I rotate mesh so it follows the detected face angle or another mesh.

[Detect angle of edges](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/259550/detect-angle-of-edges-in-geometrynodes)

Using the above method I can place either a cube or a sphere in the appropriate location. However if I have a 90degree inward facing corner piece and a 90degree outward facing corner piece the correct mesh is placed in the correct location but there rotation is not updates.

Im looking for a way to specify a rotation in radians for each mesh, that way if a have an angle of 15 degrees or -17 degrees etc I can specify which mesh to place and it will align correctly.

In the image i have three meshes, one interior and exterior 90 degree mesh and one example of a mesh with a random face angle.

Im working with the following

[image: examples]